# Chrome* api access from my page js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to find out if any tab is playing sound on my webpage. Chrome had chrome.tabs api which tells if a tab is playing any sound. How can I access those chrome apis on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, unless you make an extension to do that for you.